# "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" on its own line

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, chat

The please avoid extended discussions in comments message looks like this
[image: move to chat]

I think it would look slightly better if it looked like this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Adding a line break to keep the two sentences separate makes sense at first, but keep in mind that you're showing this in isolation. This line will inevitably appear after a long string of comments, all of which do *not* have artificially-introduced line breaks. The comparison between the two styles will look strange, and can be potentially confusing.

To get this text to work well after the preceding comments, one could either leaving this as it is **or** introducing a paragraph break, so each line is its own paragraph (more or less the same as a double line break). Since the two sentences are grammatically parts of a single thought, it makes sense to leave them as one paragraph.

Introducing possible confusion in text as the price for making it *look* better is never a good tradeoff. I suggest leaving it as it is.